# Put a default value to stdin while reading with Golang

Tags: go, stdin, reader

I am coding a sort of configuration-editor.
My goal is to allow a user to edit a complicated config file with a cli.

Every thing works well on creation but I have a little question on the edition part.

When the user makes an edit, I want to read stdin to get the new value and I want the former result to appear in stdin and be editable directly from stdin.

Little example:
- user runs : ./my-tool edit "NAME"
- We ask on stdout : "Enter the new name :"
- I want that the former result appeared in the stdin and that the user can erase it or edit it. If the former result is "test" I want test to print on console so the user can press on "del" and change "test" to "tes"

I hope I'm clear enough... Is it possible ? Thanks

My actual code :

```
func getInput(txt, def string) string {
    //def = former value/default value
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("Enter '" + txt + "' of target: ")
    os.Stdin.Write([]byte(def)) //Not working user can't edit this ...
    tmp, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return _getInput(txt, def)
    }

    tmp = strings.TrimSpace(tmp)
    fmt.Println(tmp)

    return tmp
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but this answer suggests how to overwrite the previous line in a terminal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442292/golang-how-to-have-an-inplace-string-that-updates-at-stdout

Comment: Thanks, It could be a part of the answer if I know how to listen a character and not a "string" like bufio.Reader do.

Comment: You have to put the terminal into raw mode to do this. Why not do what most cli apps do, and display a default that will be used if the user presses enter with no input?

Comment: Here's a module that you could use, or where you can at least look into how to implement something like that: https://github.com/baumgarb/rawterm

Essentially @JimB is right, you need to go into raw mode so that you have full control over the screen buffer.